# How do I add a dropdown menu in navbar?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I'd like to know how to add a dropdown menu in my navbar where the "social media" class is.  Here's my code:

```html
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Social Media</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include which css framework you are using so that people attempting to answer don't look at those classes and make an assumption.

Comment: Your html is incomplete (even nav ending tag is cut)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="navbar-nav">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Social Media</a>

  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>

  <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You have to do several things - wrap your item in 2 div tags. One is with class dropdown. This one contains the button which you click to display the actual dropdown. The other div is with class dropdown menu. This div contains your items. With newer bootstrap you can use buttons instead of link items.